# c:\windows folder has two different creations dates

Tags: windows, winapi, 64-bit

I noticed that the folder `c:\windows` has two different creation dates, depending on whether you view the file system from a 32 or 64 application.

Too test it, use the open-file-dialog of any 32/64 application and check the folder properties.

How can I get the value that 32 bit application would get, from my 64 bit application?

I already tried `Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection` in all combinations, but that seems to have no effect for this folder.

Update: In a 32-bit application I can get the "64-bit date", by using `CreateFile` and `GetFileTime`. And the "32-bit date" by using `FindFirstFile`. In a 64-bit application, both methods give me the "64-bit date".

Update:
Screenshots from properties dialog of c:\windows. Both images from the same PC.
[image]

Update 2:
I found a [source](http://www.kazamiya.net/en/NTFS_Timestamps) describing NTFS timestamps, and there are indeed 2 creation dates. I suspect that they are usually the same and that Windows 32 and 64 bit query different parts of them without anybody noticing. Deliberately accessing them seems difficult. I didn't find any API functions, just big libraries parsing the file systems table on their own. But that is getting too big for me, just for querying the timestamp, so I'll give up here.

Comment: methinks this is NTFS internals IOCTL functions might be a worthy avenue of investigation

Comment: what are the exact steps to reproduce? so far I can't

Comment: Run any 32bit program and any 64bit program. In each use the open-file-dialog. Navigate to c:\. Right-click the windows-folder and choose properties. Check the creation date.

Comment: Nope, same creation date here

Comment: @David Heffernan: Interesting. On my system I get 2018-04-11 for 32bit and 2019-03-19 for 64bit.

Comment: Are you sure you're not hitting this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130308-00/?p=5023 although two explorer should be consistent, but make sure you don't mix explorer view with API call

Comment: @Simon Mourie: Thanks, yes, I'm sure. The time difference is too big for a DST problem. And I get the same results from my code and from third-party-programs.

Comment: I tried and failed to reproduce this in a 32-bit process. There are two sets of file timestamps in NTFS, one set in the file's MFT record and another set that's replicated in the parent directory for the sake of performance when listing a directory. In some cases the two sets can get out of sync temporarily for the access, modify, and change times -- but it's weird for the create times to get out of sync. Even if they did, I don't see how WOW64 is related.  "%SystemRoot%" ("C:\\Windows") isn't subject to WOW64 redirection.

Comment: @Eryk Sun: That's worth testing. Can you give me the name of a win32 function to read the MFT record?

Comment: `GetFileTimes` is already doing that, effectively. Live in the filesystem the MFT record is in sync with the file/link control block (FCB/LCB) data. And `FindFirstFileW` queries data from the directory. It's not unusual for the two to be out of sync for the last access or modify time.

Comment: @leuk98743 What's your Windows version? And could you show some snapshots that demonstrate the create time difference?

Comment: @Rita Han - MSFT: Windows 10 Version 1903. I've updated the question with 2 screenshots.

Comment: @leuk98743l Both 32-bit and 64-bit work for me on both Windows 1903 and 1909. Can you show your reproducible sample code?

Comment: I can see from your screenshots that there are also a different number of files/folders reported. Could it be that you view different "versions" (hence the "Vorgängerversion" Tab) of the directory?